# Is it ok to ask how a particular module works?

Tags: discussion

If people have a question about setting up, or using a particular module. Does this seem like it would be a valid question for the site?

I.E;

- How do you use Drupal Views?
- How do you set up Drupal Commerce?
- How do you use Drupal Panels?

Etc..

Comment: You can request the module author in issue queue, here it is off-topic. Mostly documentation are already available and especially the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

So for those modules, "Does this seem like it would be a valid question for the site?", definitely no. All of which are complicated enough that one could write books about them. [People](https://www.drupal.org/node/2117521) [have](https://www.drupal.org/node/2117517), [literally](https://www.drupal.org/node/1849884).

I could perhaps see that one could ask similar questions for some smaller modules, but even then, we have a close reason being "unclear what you're asking", and "How do you use X" is not very specific.

Answer (score 5):

To add to what said, the Help Center also says you should ask practical questions about problems you are having. This means the question should be detailed enough to make users understand what you want to achieve, in order to make them answer correctly without guessing, and make future readers understand the problem is the same they are having.

It is more probable you have a problem with a module and you want to understand why it doesn't work as expected, or what you could have done wrong with the settings, for example.
Generally, asking how a module works is the wrong question, since you have a more specific question to ask. For that, there's probably a shorter and more helpful answer.

Asking a more specific question requires you to investigate on the problem you are having. The workflow is not the following one:

- I have a problem using a module for which I don't understand how to fix it
- I ask how the module works, hoping that one of the answers enlighights me on the obscure point I missed

A little effort is required from the users who ask a question; they should try to resolve their problem before posting the question. This helps avoiding asking a question for which the solution comes out few minutes after asking the question. In most of the cases, the problem was a typo in the code, forgetting to enable a module, or installing the module in the wrong directory (just to name a few), and the question would not be helpful to future users, which is what Stack Exchange aims to do.

Assuming that is all the text appearing in the question, those questions are too broad, and the first one seems a poll too.